# Return first field of text file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with ~ as delimiter. The first field is the Account Number. I want to return a list of Account Numbers in the file. Currently I know only how to return all content excluding the header line:

```
get-content $dest\$FPP.txt | select -Skip 1
```

How can I amend this to return everything left of the first ~ character, in all lines excluding line 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import it as csv:

```
Import-Csv $dest\$FPP.txt -Delimiter '~' | Foreach-Object {$_.'Account Number'}
```

Comment: Sorry, I realised now that when I send this list of accounts via email, it adds them next to each other in the same line. Any idea how I can list them below one another?

Comment: Yes, pipe the list to Out-String and assign the result to the Body parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the SubString method. By using SubString you can pick out a string out of your text file by indicating the start and ending position.

For Example:
PS > "Hello_World".substring(0,5)
Hello